# Why can I access an array in my Redux store?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have a Redux reducer and I am trying to nest an array of objects within my reduce, but it is breaking. I don't seem to have access to anything in the array. However, if I return an array instead of an object from the reducer it works fine.

```
const friendReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  console.log(action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_FRIENDS':
      return {
        list: [
          ...state,
          ...action.payload,
        ],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  } 
};

export default friendsReducer;
```

When I try to access the `list` in my connected components, I can't access the `Array#splice` method or `Array#length` property. Here are other relevant parts of the code:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    friends: state.friends,
  }
};

const rootReducer = {
  friends: friendsReducer,
};

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    ...rootReducer,
    router: routerReducer,
  }),
  {}, // initial state
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    applyMiddleware(routerMiddleware(history)),
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
    (typeof window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ !== 'undefined') ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() : f => f,
  ),
);

export default store;
```

Comment: check question for edit

Comment: SOrry i will edit the main question it looks very cluttered

Comment: sorry, i fixed it, forgot to edit it as i copied it

Comment: Should be `friends: state.friends.list` to get the actual array of friends.

Comment: even when i use that i still get the same issues, will try again
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: Your initial state should be: `state = { list: [] }`

Comment: sigh i feel like a complete idiot. Forgot you have to initialize every object within the state. blah it works now

Comment: No problem. I can add an answer with some explanation if you want, for future readers.

Comment: You should, and i can mark down it as an answer, I have question if i had a nested object for eg. would i need to intialize the nested object too? I had another reducer which was would take `state = {}` and i would be returning `{uid: action.uid}` but i didnt need to initialize it like i did the array. Is this something for an array only?

Comment: You tried to access a *property of `list`*. You can't access a property of `undefined`, but you can access `undefined` itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a few problems. For one, `friendsReducer`'s slice of state returns an *object*, not an array. So your state looks like this:

```
{
  friends: {
    list: […]
  }
}
```

So when you `mapStateToProps`, it should look like this if you want the array:

```
return {
  friends: state.friends.list //not state.friends, that's an object
}
```

Next, also notice that your initial state doesn't contain `list` in it:

```
const friendReducer = (state = {}, action) => { … }
```

So when you first try to access the `length` of `list`, there will be *no `list` property*, so you have to set it as an empty array inside your initial state. Always set up your initial state with all the properties:

```
const friendReducer = (state = { list: [] }, action) => { … }
```

Finally, you're spreading the wrong property of state in your reducer:

```
case 'GET_FRIENDS':
  return {
    ...state, //here use ...state to spread previous state
    list: [
      ...state.list, //not state, use state.list to spread previous list
      ...action.payload,
    ],
  };
```

You want to spread the old `list`, so you're supposed to spread `state.list`, not `state` itself. Also, you can add `...state` outside of `list` to spread the previous state for good measure, assuming you'll have more than one action, though its good practice nonetheless.

Comment: You're also trying to spread `...state`, which is an object, into the `list` array inside your reducer. Change that to `...state.list`.

Comment: @KyleRichardson Good catch!

Comment: Good answer; I'm assuming you'll add that into your answer. Going to up vote.